# Searching for a list of names in a piece of text

Tags: php, search

I have a list of 230 names in a database and I'd like to monitor a Twitter feed for mentions of occurrences of those names, particularly when multiple names are used in the one tweet.

I'm not quite sure how to do this.

My initial thought is:

Store names in an array and run every tweet through a function like this:

```
function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `preg_grep('/(john|jane|fred)/', $arr)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a fine approach, though I would consider a variation which returns a little more information through the interface than a boolean, since you said you are interested in multiple mentions. It will execute longer when there *is* a mention but seems worth it:

```
function referenceCount($str, array $arr)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably but some logic in place of the boolean to highlight who has been mentioned. I haven't got that far yet though.